# how to subscribe to multiple topics without passing a list and without using patterns

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka I know that I can subscribe my consumer to multiple topics doing:

1. passing directly the list of topics I want to subscribe to.
2. Or passing a pattern

In my case I cannot pass directly a list of topics or a pattern because the list of topics is not known in advance.

For example a user will specify a topic in the morning by using a UI (for example), and a second topic in the evening, so the consumer will finish subscribed to these two topics.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` API of the KafkaConsumer to dynamically change the subscriptions of your consumer.

If you sent a message to one of the subscribed topics with `key=subscribe/unsubscribe` and `value=topic1/topic2/...` you could implement a logic in your consumer that changes its subscriptions based on those messages.